# Производительность запросов и большие таблицы.

Tags: производительность, база-данных, sql-server, sql

MSSQL Server. Есть огромная таблица (> 15 000 000 записей). Записи содержат уникальный идентификатор записи (ключ таблицы), неуникальный идентификатор (софтины, которая пишет в базу) в виде строки, timestamp и другие, менее интересные данные. В хранимой процедуре (CLR SP) хочу сначала собрать все не уникальные идентификаторы, затем, итерируясь по ним, собирать интересующие данные:

```
// Псевдокод

list_of_serials = SELECT [SerialNo] FROM [Table] GROUP BY [SerialNo];

foreach( serial in list_of_serials )
{
    rowset =    SELECT  
                        *
                FROM    
                        [Table]
                WHERE  
                        [SerialNo] = @serial
                        AND
                        [Timestamp] BETWEEN
                                        @startDate 
                                        AND
                                        @endDate;
                ORDER BY
                        [Timestamp]
    // Обработка результатов
}
```

Беда в том, что каждый запрос длится минимум 10 минут с локальной базой. Пытаюсь курить индексы, но ощутимых результатов добится пока не удалось. Как с этой проблемой можно бороться? Дополнительные мета-таблицы и триггеры делать уже поздно =) Буду признателен за любые идеи.

Попутно еще вопрос по .Net : есть смысл сначала собрать данные в `IEnumerable<...>`, обрабатывая затем их средствами Linq или каждый раз делать запрос в базу? (Имеем дело с **CLR SP**).

Comment: А один запрос

   SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [Timestamp] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate GROUP BY [SerialNo];

с записью результата в файл тоже 10 минут идет?

Comment: Забыл добавить еще ORDER BY-условие.

@avp
Да. Даже первый запрос длится больше 5-7 минут.

Comment: @Free_ze, а сколько записей получается в результате (по всем SerialNo  для одного BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate)?

Может их просто очень много (в Вашем случае, скажем, 1 000 000). Тогда ускорить все-равно не удастся.

Comment: @avp

    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Table] WHERE [Timestamp] BETWEEN '20130101' AND '20140101' GROUP BY [SerialNumber]

максимум вышло - 450 000, запрос занял 18 минут =)

То есть, меня даже правильные индексы могут не спасти с такой архитектурой БД?

Comment: может только увеличение мощностей и вынос базы на отдельный сервер...

Comment: @Free_ze, думаю (при таком объеме выборки), что дело даже не в архитектуре базы, а *принципиально в постановке задачи*.

Скорость реально нужна для интерактивных задач. Какие разумные оперативные действия могут быть произведены с полмиллионом (да даже с парой тысяч) строк ответа?

Comment: @avp

Проблема здесь не столько в размере самой выборки, сколько в поиске значений, который то и дело срывается в тупой перебор многомиллионной таблицы.
Сейчас я открыл для себя такой инструмент, как "План выполнения" (Execution Plan), отражающий в том числе используемые индексы. С помощью него смог составить необходимый индекс. Он вряд ли идеален, но все серийники теперь вычекиваются за 6 секунд, а информация по конкретному из них - за ~25 секунд. Уже не 7 и 12 минут =)

Comment: Сегодня начал читать книгу Рефакторинг SQL-приложений Авторы: Паскаль Лерми, Стефан Фаро вот там как раз и происходит описание методик для решения подобных проблем. Посмотрите на досуге, пригодится думаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблему решил самостоятельно.
Помог инструмент "**Display Estimated Execution Plan**" (пункт в контекстном меню внутри текстового редактора запросов в **SQL Management Studio**), который графически отображает планируемые этапы обработки запроса (в т.ч. используемые индексы) и процентное отношение ко времени.
В такой большой таблице, как моя, нужно уйти от полного перебора (по ключу, кластерный индекс). Структура такая:

```
[ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[SerialNo] [varchar](60) NOT NULL,
[Timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Variable1] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[Variable2] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
.....
```

Мне необходимо выбрать сначала все значения [SerialNo], затем, для них найти значения [Variable2], где [Timestamp] лежит от @startDate до @endDate.

```
-- Step #1

SELECT  
        [SerialNo]
FROM    
        [Table] 
WHERE   
        [Variable1] = 'needed_value'
        AND
        [Timestamp] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
GROUP BY
        [SerialNo]

-------------------------------------

-- Step #2

SELECT 
        [Timestamp]
        ,[Variable2]
FROM    
        [Table]
WHERE 
        [SerialNo] = @serial
        AND
        [Variable1] = 'needed_value'
        AND 
        [Timestamp] BETWEEN  @startDate AND @endDate 
ORDER BY
        [Timestamp]
```

Нужен свой индекс. Он будет не кластерный (ибо он может быть только один и это ключ таблицы). Туда я не стесняясь запихнул (по порядку):

```
[SerialNo],
[Timestamp],
[Variable1],
[Variable2]
```

Как итог: список серийников извлекаются за 2 секунды (первый запрос), информация по каждому из них (второй запрос) извлекается менее, чем за секунду.